# Send data to ddatabase by using ajax and php in symfony

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

1. twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <!-- Dodaj link do jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
        <h1>Projekcik dla septema</h1>


        <form method="POST" action="{{ path('post') }}" id="postForm">
            Wiadomość:<br>
            <textarea name="wiadomosc" id="wiadomosc" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="wyślij" onclick="ajaks(event)">
        </form>
<div id="tableContainer">
    <table style='border: 1px solid black'>
        <tr style='border: 1px solid black'>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>wiadomość</th>
            <th>godzina</th>
            <th>nazwa użytkownika</th>
        </tr>
        
        {% for post in posts %}
            <tr style='border: 1px solid black'>
                <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.text }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.time|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.getUserId().getUsername() }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>

    <form method="post" action="{{ path('logout') }}">
        <input type="submit" value="wyloguj">
    </form>

  
    <script>
function ajaks(event){
    event.preventDefault();
let post = {
  text: $("#wiadomosc").val(),
  time: new Date().toISOString(),
  user_id: 1
};
console.log(post);
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ path('post') }}",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
      'post': JSON.stringify(post)
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
  } 
</script>
      <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        setInterval(refreshTable, 2000);
    });

    function refreshTable() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('showTable') }}",  
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#tableContainer').html(data);
            }
            });
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

2. controler:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/PostController.php


namespace App\Post\Controller;
use App\User\Entity\User;
use App\Post\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Post\Service\CreatePost;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class PostController extends AbstractController
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    #[Route('/post', name: 'post')]
    public function createPost(Request $request, CreatePost $createPost, SessionInterface $session): Response
    {
        if($session->get('online') === 'false'){
            return $this->render('user/register.html.twig', ['posts' => '']);
        }
    
        $userId = $session->get('user_id');
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);
       
        if ($user) {
            $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $post = $data['post'] ?? null;
            $post = json_decode($post, true); 

            if ($post === null) {
                die('post is null');
            }
         
            var_dump($request->getContent());
    
            if (!isset($post['text'])) {
                die('text is not set in post');
            }
    
            $createPost->create($post['text'], $user);
        }     
    
        return $this->redirectToRoute('show');
    }
    

    

    #[Route('/showTable', name: 'showTable')]
    public function showTable(SessionInterface $session): Response
    {

        if($session->get('online') === 'false'){
        return new Response('');
        }

        $posts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->findAll();

        return $this->render('post/table.html.twig', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
    
    #[Route('/show', name: 'show')]
    public function showPost(Request $request, CreatePost $createPost,SessionInterface $session): Response
    {
        if($session->get('online') === 'false'){
            return $this->render('user/register.html.twig', ['posts' => '']);
        }
        $posts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->findAll();
     
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }   

}
```

i have problem with sending data to database. when i try to send object to my route i got infomation (post is null) but when i wrote my object in twig file before sending everything works. can somebody say what im doing wrong? i tried everything. other functions in my  code work without problem. Before when i useed only php to send data everything worked. when i had only web reolading - that worked too.

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
Accept-Language: pl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7 
Cache-Control: max-age=0 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 23 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ibdbokf0mprjb17sedhcdh7gbu 
Host: localhost:8000 
Mod-Rewrite: On 
Origin: http://localhost:8000 
Referer: http://localhost:8000/show 
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24" 
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0 
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows" 
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document 
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate 
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin 
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1 
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0 
X-Php-Ob-Level: 1 
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ibdbokf0mprjb17sedhcdh7gbu wiadomosc=fswessfsfsfsf
```

Comment: I dbout your symfony route is expecting JSON wrapped inside something else. Look at your network tool and examine the payload of your ajax request. You're posting a JSON string wrapped inside a named variable in a form-url-encoded post overall. Doesn't make a lot of sense. Try with just `data: post` in the AJAX options (jQuery will take care of encoding it for you). Or if you want to send JSON, set the correct content-type header and _just_ send the JSON-encoded string (not wrapped inside anything else)

Comment: @ADyson i did exactly what you said and its still not working... it is possible a problem is with connection or somewhere else than my code?

Comment: Well you said it's connecting but that the data in `$request` is null? Is that correct? I wasn't quite clear on the exact debugging you've done. For example what does `$request->getContent()` show (without trying to json_decode it)?

Comment: Also, am I right in assuming we're talking about the `public function createPost` function and `$.ajax({
  url: "{{ path('post') }}",`...call? There is more than one in your code. Try to reduce your question to a [mre] of the issue (you can [edit] it) so there's no confusion or distraction.

Comment: @ADyson it not supposted to be null, data in $request supposted to be object type with text, time and id_user files. i creating these fields in twig.

Comment: how would you connect this two ajax fuctions into one?

Comment: Well you could get the first call to return the table data directly, instead of needing a second request to fetch it

Comment: `$request supposted to be`... I know, but I'm asking you to debug and check _exactly_ what it _does_ contain

Comment: when i die $request its output POST /post HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,... itd. any way its not null. okey i try this : get the first call to return the table data directly.

Comment: Unrelated, you're missing a `<body>`. And I'm not sure why this template `extends 'base.html.twig'` when it has all the HTML code in it

Comment: ok i did everything you said, i have still the same error

Comment: its supposted to be twig file beacuse i working in symfony.

Comment: `still the same error` ...which you haven't really explained clearly, still. Of `$request` you said `its output POST /post HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml`...but that's only just the start of the headers, it doesn't show me anything useful about the rest of it. Please [edit] your question with such info then you can show it in full, in context, and properly formatted. Thanks.

Comment: as your fish i did it

Comment: Thanks. Strange, it still shows only headers, even though a content-length of 23 is suggested. Is that the output of your `var_dump($request->getContent()); command`?

Comment: (If it _isn't_, please also show the output of `var_dump($request->getContent());`)

Comment: Also please edit your question to show the AJAX code you are now using. so we can see if you followed all instructions correctly. And is there any particular reason you're using jQuery 1.10? That's an ancient version, and not even the latest release in the 1.x branch. Unless you specifically need to support old obsolete browsers such as Internet Explorer, then there should be no reason why you can't use the latest jQuery, and thus ensure you get better performance bug fixes etc. It might even help with this issue, conceivably.

Comment: P.S. `when i useed only php to send data`...you can't use PHP to send data _from_ a browser. PHP only runs on the server. I think you mean when you only used a HTML form to send the data. I only mention this because using the correct terminology is important for programmers - it helps you to search accurately about problems and to get new knowledge, and it avoids the potential for confusion when explaining your situation to other people. And it's also important that you understand the components in your application and what their roles are.

Comment: its finnaly works, thank you a lot! You are my super hero thank you!

Comment: No problem. What did you change in the end, then? Please add your solution, with code and a brief description, as an Answer below if it would help others with a similar issue :-).